# Removing event listener (DOM Level 0 way)

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

I know for DOM Level 2 methods like `addEventListener` and `removeEventListener`, so I am not interested in that.
My question is what way to use for unbinding events if you must use DOM 0 events like `elem.onclick = function() {}`. How to do that ?

Comment: yes that would work, or `onclick=null`

Comment: `must use` this ugly way in 2015?

Comment: DOM Level 0 / Quirksmode is not '2015'. Old technology requires old solutions.

Comment: Guys I know, it's old, don't get me to literal. I don't use this in real world.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own simple version of unbind

```
Object.prototype.unbind(evt) {
    if(this[evt]) {
      this[evt] = null;
    }
}
...
element.unbind("onclick");
```

Look this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7hzzotkp/)

Comment: I like that. I tried `delete` as well but that doesn't seem to work. Coincidentally in Chrome it seems to break the property ignoring any new assignments.